# using google java api library in clojure

Tags: java, clojure

1. I'm trying to require a java library by Google and call it from Clojure.
2. I added [`com.google.api-client/google-api-client`](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup#google-api-client) to my project.clj according to the groupId, artifactId and version.
3. `lein deps` returns no output - seems like it setups all the dependencies successfully.
4. I have checked the classpath, and it contains the google-api-client.jar `(System/getProperty "java.class.path").`
5. `user=>(require 'com.google.api-client/google-api-client)` returns `FileNotFoundException Could not locate google_api_client__init.class or google_api_client.clj on classpath:   clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:443)`

Here is my `project.clj`:

```clj
(defproject textsync "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [com.google.api-client/google-api-client "1.18.0-rc"]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have to import a java class into the clojure namespace like,

```clj
(import 'org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils) ;replace the java file with what you want
```

`require` is only for importing other clojure name spaces. You have to use import when you are importing java classes into clojure name spaces.

Comment: `(import 'com.google.api-client/google-api-client)`,`(import com.google.api-client.google-api-client)`,`(import 'com.google.api-client)` doesn't work (`ClassNotFoundException`).

Comment: `(import '[com.google.api-client])`.  That will not resolve all of the problems.  You may need a `use` or `require` as well, but I haven't gotten that to work yet with this library.

Comment: @wie : You can't import whole package. You need to import all the classes you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You most probably simply need to import the classes you want. For instance, you may want to try :

```clj
(import '[com.google.api.client.googleapis GoogleUtils]
        '[com.google.api.client.googleapis.services AbstractGoogleClient
                                                    AbstractGoogleClient$Builder])
```

Note that :

1. the class is spelled `com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleUtils` (with no dash)
2. the Clojure syntax for Java nested classes uses `$`.